# How do I take a screen shot of my Xvfb buffer?

Tags: chrome, display, imagemagick, screenshot, xvfb

I'm using Amazon Linux.  I want to run a headless chromium browser to use on my node.js Selnium tests.  So I fire up my Xvfb server like so ...

```
if ! pidof /usr/bin/Xvfb; then Xvfb :0 -screen 5 1024x768x8 & fi
```

However, when I try and take a screenshot after my tests have failed,

```
DISPLAY=:0 import -window root /tmp/screenshot.png
```

I get the error mentioned below...

```
+ DISPLAY=:0
+ import -window root /tmp/screenshot.png
import: unable to open X server `:0' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/369.
```

How do I take a screenshot of Xvfb buffer?

Comment: Your example works fine here (debian 9). You can try `xwd` and `xwud` instead of `image`, works here, too. Maybe check again whether Xvfb is still running, and running on :0?

Comment: Do you hvea an example of what you're talking about -- e.g. using another tool besides imagemagick?

Comment: it is similar to your example. `xwd -display :0 -root -out /tmp/pic` takes a snapshot, and `xwud -in /tmp/pic` shows it.

Comment: Wrks on RHEL/CentOS 7 too. @mviereck you must write an answer.

Comment: I see an error says unable to open X server, it should be a problem that the X server  itself is not reachable

Answer (score 10):

I tried something similar (on another distribution and to take a screenshot of an xterm window, but this should not be much different)
I had to use display :1 as display :0 is already used :

```
$ Xvfb :1 -screen 5 1024x768x8 &
[1] 23728
$ pidof /usr/bin/Xvfb
23728
$ DISPLAY=:1 xterm 2>/dev/null &
[2] 23767
$ DISPLAY=:1 xwd -root -silent | convert xwd:- png:/tmp/screenshot.png
$
```

And I have a "/tmp/screenshot.png" file with the expected xterm window on a black background.
You can also use

```
xwd -display :1 -root -silent | convert xwd:- png:/tmp/screenshot.png
```

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu: To install `xwd` and `convert`, run: `apt-get install x11-apps imagemagick`